# How to send the array in $_POST array in ajax using form.serialize()

Tags: arrays, ajax

How to send the array in `$_POST` array in ajax (data : `form.serialize()`) form data is  like `array('name'=>'test','accom'=>array(0=>'test2'.1=>'test3'))` :

```
$.ajax({            
    url     :   'add_tour_apply_control.php',
    type    :   "POST",
    dataType:   "json",
    data    :   $('#form_tour_mov').serialize(),
    success :   function (messData){
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/).

It will directly encode form elements as an array of **names and values**.

Then send the array of values across to your data field.

For example - `var fields = $("#form_tour_mov").serializeArray();`.
Then `field.value` will have the values from the form.